# How do I import a file/list from a server/website using Python

Tags: python

I would like to have an always updating list by using standard txt file that python has to grab from a server/website.

Example

```
    women =["Dare1","Dare2","Dare3","Dare4","Dare5","Dare6"]

   men = ["Dare1","Dare2","Dare3","Dare4","Dare5","Dare6"]
```

Then once the program is reopened, it grab the updated txt

```
    women =["Dare1","Dare2","Dare3","Dare4","Dare5","Dare6","Dare7"]

   men = ["Dare1","Dare2","Dare3","Dare4","Dare5","Dare6"]
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, just link your code to the files location on web server....Every time it is opened. Use urllib.

Comment: Don't use urllib. You will be much happier with the API of requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

So this text file is generated/updated automatically on your target server?  If you know the url where this text file is displayed, it's as simple as implementing a `urlretrieve` using python's `urllib` module to retrieve it and implementing a `cron` on your own system so as to periodically run that python script.

Here's an example of its usage:-

```
fName = "CFE_{0}{1}_VX.csv".format(m_codes[month],str(year)[-2:])
save_path = os.path.join(path, fName)
if os.path.exists(save_path) or forceDownload:
    print 'File already downloaded, skipping'
    return

urlStr = "http://cfe.cboe.com/Publish/ScheduledTask/MktData/datahouse/{0}".format(fName)
print 'Getting: %s' % urlStr
try:
    print save_path
    urlretrieve(urlStr, save_path)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

In this case, I am downloading a csv file from the Chicago Board Options Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, this will get in the right path. I'm sort of a newbie in python, so server stuff is brand spanking new.

Comment: No sweat. Let me know if this is what you need or if you have any other questions.